# Monaco-editor automatic language detection doesn't work

Tags: monaco-editor

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57074528) answer on how to let monaco automatically detect the language of your file:

```js
const model = monaco.editor.createModel(fileContent, undefined, filePath/* full path to the file */);
editor.setModel(model);
```

The content of the file does show up in the editor, but there's no syntax highlighting, just white text. I also tried replacing `filePath` with `fileName` (base name of the file), however, it still doesn't work. Is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 1):

The `monaco.editor.createModel` function third parameter must be a [Uri](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/classes/monaco.Uri.html), not a simple string.
You can create a Uri from a filename, as specified in the answer you linked :

```js
const model = monaco.editor.createModel(fileContent, undefined, monaco.Uri.file(fileName));
editor.setModel(model);
```